# Multiple ng-bind in the same directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-bind

I'm trying to use multiple ng-bind instead of {{}} in a directive, but with no luck.

```
<my-directive att1="age" att2="22"></my-directive>

angular
    .module("app",[])
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            att1: '@',
            att2: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="ng-bind: att1;" ng-bind="att2"></div>'
    }
}
```

No problem in case there's only one ng-bind. In case I have more than one, as in this case, I read somewhere about the notation I'm using `"ng-bind: att;"` but it's not working.

Also, I wonder if I'd really would need it. Apparently using ng-bind avoid the problem of the double bracket flashing in the screen before the data is loaded, which in this case it's not really important as I'm using the value as a class attribute and thus is not being displayed in the screen. On the other hand it's supposed to be more efficient using ng-bind.

Any ideas? I've seen a couple questions here in stackoverflow regarding this but none of them seem to resolve the matter.

Answer (score 1):

You only can have one `ng-bind` per attribute. The value of `ng-bind` is written as the content of your `div` tag. When you have multiple `ng-bind`s they would overwrite each other, so this is not possible.

However, if you want to set a class, have a look at the `ngClass` directive here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass. Your template could look sth like this:

```
template: '<div ng-class="att1" ng-bind="att2"></div>'
```

This would set the content of `att1` into the `class="..."` attribute of your `div` and the content of `att2` as the content of your `div`. The rendered output could be

```
<div class="your-att1-value">your att2 value</div>
```

If you want more than one `ng-bind` you could insert a seperat tag for each ng-bind like this:

```
template: '<div><span ng-bind="att1"></span><span ng-bind="att2"></span></div>'
```

Comment: It doesn´t work for me, what if I need a directive based on an image, as in `<img src="{{att1}}" alt="{{att2}}"></img>`? In this case I see no way to do it, I can´t use separate tags.

Comment: For this, you can use the `ngSrc` directive. For the alt tag, I think the double curly brace syntax is safe.